# What are the side effects of a full root partition?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ubuntu-12.04

I have a mission critical server running that I cannot take down (or at least, I'm told I can't right now).

It unfortunately filled it's root partition up.

It's running a custom process that's writing some log files and since I'm mostly a developer I wanted to fix the way the program logs to make it compatible with logrotate since it's not right now.

So I'm needing to persuade the lead developer that fixing this is worthwhile and should be a high priority.  For the moment I can compress the logs and scp them offsite since they are wanting to be kept for a long time for analysis.  But some days the server gets heavy traffic and logs ALOT of data filling the disk before I can get a chance to do anything.  Once the disk is full, compressing large files without any space to spare isn't possible.  And since they are large, copying to another server could take quite some time.

So I need some leverage to help push up the priority of this.  What are the side effects of a full root partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The severity of a full root partition can be mitigated a little if other parts of the filesystem are on their own partitions.  However just picture what any process may do if it can't write to the filesystem and gets an error instead.

As an exmple the /var/run/*.pid files can't be created by any process that uses this mechanism (and lots do), they should fail to start or just crash or they may repeatedly try and start, not detect they have started already due to no pid file being present and start a new instance, until the out-of-memory killer process fires up and starts killing stuff at mostly random.

Side effects can include but are not limited to

- the server crashing unexpectedly in the middle of the night while the admin(s) are on holidays, heavily asleep, etc...
- depending on how your custom application is written it may not handle that crash in any sort of reasonable fashion and corrupt itself to the point where you need to restore from backup.  Most developers first thoughts when testing are not, "what happens if I yank the power cord out..... NOW!  WOW that didn't kill it, what about if I do it....... NOW"

You do have backups right...

How long would it take to

- realise you can't recover the existing system in any sort of reasonable timeframe
- possibly setup a new machine (so you take out the old one for analysis for some hopeful info recovery)
- actually restore from backup

How much will management like that sort of downtime and data loss...?

Comment: Thanks that's actually useful.  It's mission critical but is actually a stateless server so deploying a new one is easy.  It's just that taking it offline could affect a lot of people.

Comment: even though my answer sounds sarcastic, it is not.  I've had both windows and linux servers crash because file systems were full. The server can take itself offline, and Murphy's Law will make sure it happens at the worst time.  It may not be the whole system but if the mission critical app stops, it might as well be.